# finding all "tree-like" vertices in a DAG

Tags: graph, tree, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am looking for an algorithm in DAG, which would identify all vertices, that satisfy following requirement for given vertex V: ***all*** paths from **any** predecessor of V to **any** successor of V contain vertex V. This includes both **direct** and **indirect** predecessors and successors.

Input DAG, will always have a single root and will be connected.

I think that the root and leaves meet the requirement above, there's an empty set of paths and "all of them" contain anything you want :). In any case, it's trivial to find those.

Note: If DAG is a polytree, the result contains all of the vertices.

For example, in the following DAG (all of the edges are pointing downwards), I'd like to find all vertices, which are marked by the uppercase letters.

```
         (A) 
        / | \
       b  |  \
     / |  |   \
    c (J) r    \
    |    /     (K)
    |  /      /   \
    |/       /     \
   (D)      l       o
    | \      \     / \
    |  \      \   /  (P) 
    e   h      (M)     \
    |  / \       \     (Q)  
    | /  (I)     (N) 
   (F)               
    |                
   (G)
    |
   (H)
```

Any ideas? Does this problem have a name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DAG is [partial order set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set), and latter approach is easier to describe in poset terms.

Since DAG is rooted it is equivalent to change "any predecessor" with a root.

If vertex B has more than one immediate predecessor. Call them B1, B2, ..., Bk. Set A = [join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_and_meet) of B1, B2, ..., Bk. It has exists since DAG is rooted. Vertices V with A < V < B (A is predecessor to V and B is successor to V) can't be in solution set.

Outline of algorithm is the same as upper description:

```
solution_set = all vertices
for vertex B that has more incoming edges
   (a) find A join (B1, B2, ..., Bk)
   (b) remove all V, A < V < B, from solution_set
```

Implementation of lines a and b can be done by storing predecessors for each vertex. That can be found by [topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Let P(v) be set of all predecessors of vertex v.

Line a is implemented like. Let I be intersection of P(B1), P(B2), ..., P(Bk). Find largest vertex in I that is reachable from root by only one path that is wholy in a I. It is done by traversing from root and looking if only one successor of last path vertex is in I.

Line b is just P(B) - P(A) - A.

Answer (score 0):

I believe checking that a vertex V, such that the average neighbor degree of V is zero, should be a good starting point to your question.

If the average neighbor degree of V is zero, then there is no path between any of the neighbors of V to each other. Since both the successor S and predecessor P are of V are counted as its neighbors in the function below, a path between P and S will contain V.

NB: This DOES NOT GUARANTEE UNIQUENESS of V, i.e. the path between P and S could include some other node U. Is this alright for you? My answer works if successor nodes cannot be connected to other successor nodes of V, and similarly, predecessor nodes cannot be connected to other predecessors of V.

Also by successors and predecessors, do you mean IMMEDIATE successors/predecessors? I am not sure if my technique will work for non-immediate ones, but if for immediate without connections between them, average neighbor degree should work.

Since you mention DAG, you will already have a Directed Graph data-structure, hence running average neighbor degree on this data-structure should be fine.

NetworkX is the library I am most comfortable with, so this is the function I would use:

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.5/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.neighbor_degree.average_neighbor_degree.html#networkx.algorithms.neighbor_degree.average_neighbor_degree

The above function lets you specify the nodes in the graph that you want to analyze. So feed it node V and all the S and the P nodes. It should return a dict of average neighbor degree for all the nodes. From the dict extract the value for node V and check if it's zero

It would be difficult to help you further without some code or sample data-structure from your side. I can update this answer with some NetworkX code if you can provide me some starting code

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think it will work. As you said, it won't work if indirect successors/predecessors are in question and that's exactly what I was asking about. Will edit the question to put this part in bold.